# C# null reference exception, how to spot the culprit in the specified line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, nullreferenceexception

We are all tired of this kind of exceptions, but is there a way to quickly find the offending thing? Usually this kind of exception is thrown in a line like this:

```
var myVar = somethingUninitallized.property;
```

And it's easy to see that the right hand side of the assignment is the cause. However there are times when the lines are long like this:

```
var myVar = x.DoSomething(y.FirstDoThis(isThisInitiallized).aProperty, z.ThenDoThis(whatAboutThis).anotherProperty).ComplicatingThings().thisHappensSometimes;
```

And we get the exception on that line. Yes we could have written the code differently, but could be the case that we might be debugging other people's code and modifying it would require to recompile for 15 minutes, require authorization, or any other impediment. This is a trivial example, and I can think on linq too, but surely there are other even more complicated scenarios. I usually inspect each thing one by one still in the year 2020.

**Is it impossible to have from the debugger tools or somehow, which is the thing with a null reference?**

Comment: Write a UnitTest. You should even be able to "step through" this. If I were you, I'd prefer to bite the sour apple and refactor this to something maintainable.

Comment: *"Yes we could have written the code differently"* Sounds like a valid option to me - if you have code similar to that given in your sample, it will always be a nightmare to debug. Spending a few minutes to make the code more readable and maintainable, rather than trying to cram everything into a single line, will save hours  in the long run.

Comment: BTW `var myVar = somethingUninitallized;` is perfectly fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EbiIEB , what gets you is something like `var myVar = somethingUninitallized.SomeProperty;`

Comment: @Fildor To be more specific `var myVar = somethingUninitallized;` is *not* fine, but it will generate a compile-time error (use of unassigned variable), not a `NullReferenceException` (in your fiddle, `o` is initialized to `null`).

Comment: @RufusL Ooops, yes. Right. But the point was it doesn't throw, so. Yes, you 're right.

Comment: The only way the debugger is going to know after the fact which part was null is if either the compiler creates fake local variables that the debugger understands, or that the debugger re-evaluates your expression according to the C# rules. Neither is optimal.

Comment: @Rufus L There are workarounds like improving the code or writing unit tests as Fildor stated. However, imagine the scenario where we would have the debugger telling us that there is an error in x file without specifying the line. We would require that somehow, this is the same. We have the line now, is it possible to know which thing is null without modifying the code or inspecting each part of the line?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do you mean something like moving the yellow arrow one step up and re executing that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer copied from [Debugging System.NullReferenceException](https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/), writen by [Thomas Ardel](https://blog.elmah.io/author/thomas/):

---

**Using Null Reference Analysis in Visual Studio**

If you are on Visual Studio 2017 or newer, you will have the Null Reference Analysis feature available. With this in place, Visual Studio can show you exactly what is null. Let's use this example of method-chaining:

```
var street = service.GetUser().Address.Street;
```

To enable the analysis go to *Debug | Windows | Exception Settings*. Check *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* (if not already checked) or extend the node and check the exceptions you are interested in.

In this case, you can check *System.NullReferenceException*. When running the code, the debugger breaks on the `NullReferenceException` and you now see the *Exception Thrown* window:

[image]

Voila! The window says "ConsoleApp18.User.Address.**get** returned null". Exactly what we wanted to see.

Comment: Awesome! It seems that my solution's debugger is for some reason not working as expected https://i.imgur.com/9RYqpfw.png . I tested it in a Console app and it's working there, so I'll have to investigate this further.